# Выравнивание div'ов в одной строке а то получается не понятно что

Tags: php, html

Вынося данные из базы данных создается 20 блоков максимум но блоки идут друг под другом и как я не пытался их выровнять ничего не получаеться[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.col-lg-4{-webkit-box-flex:0;-ms-flex:0 0 33.333333%;flex:0 0 33.333333%;max-width:33.333333%}
.card{position:relative;display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;min-width:0;word-wrap:break-word;background-color:#fff;background-clip:border-box;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);border-radius:.25rem}
.card-body{-webkit-box-flex:1;-ms-flex:1 1 auto;flex:1 1 auto;padding:1.25rem}
.card-title{margin-bottom:.75rem}.card-subtitle{margin-top:-.375rem;margin-bottom:0}
```

```php
<h3 style="text-align:center">Последние 20 бонусов</h3>
 <?PHP
$db->Query("SELECT * FROM widget ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20");
if($db->NumRows() > 0){  
while($bon = $db->FetchArray()){
$st200=$bon["id"];      
        ?>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
<h4 class="card-title">Сhart</h4>
<div id="morris-area-chart1"><?=sprintf("%.0f",$st200); ?></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>          
<?PHP
        }

    }else echo '<tr><td align="center" colspan="5">Нет записей</td></tr>'
  ?>
```

Comment: думаю php здесь совсем не причем.. посмотрите свойство float в сss ( ваш вопрос решит или float:left или display: inline-block )

Comment: Извините пожалуйста я пробовал и свойство float:left или display: inline-block но что-то не выходит можити помочь если не трудно

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
<обобщающий div> {
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr #короче fr это часть количество fr'ов в свойстве 
#это сколько div'ов будет в линии
}
```

Comment: Извините не получается так тоже пробывал

Comment: так ты ширину поменьше сделай или тебе надо чтобы за границу выходило?

Comment: да тут дело в том что блок все равно становиться под первым блоком а не сбоку

Comment: попробуй убрать max-width если не сработает я хз

Comment: когда я добавляю блоки в ручную все добавляется и выглядит как надо